# Dispose the correct SPSite object for garbage collection

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-addin, spsite, dispose

I have these lines of code:

```
string siteUrl = "http://myTestSite";
using (SPSite siteCollectionParent = new SPSite(strUrl))
{
    SPWebApplication webApplication = siteCollectionParent.WebApplication;
    SPSiteCollection childCollections = webApp.Sites;
    foreach(SPSite siteCollectionChild in childCollections)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Console.Writeline(siteCollectionChild.Url);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Add here some code
        }
    }
}
```

I want to dispose the SPSite object. Which is the best solution to dispose it? Adding `siteCollectionChild.Dispose()` , adding `childCollections.Dispose()` or `siteCollectionParent` is disposed by garbage collection?

Comment: Are apps capable of running the server object model?  I thought you had to use CSOM with apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write:

```
using (SPSite siteCollectionParent = new SPSite(strUrl))
```

you don't need to dispose because the using-Method will do this for you as you guessed. But this has no impact on your child-Instances!
So for disposing your siteCollectionChild you can write

```
 foreach(SPSite siteCollectionChild in childCollections)
    {
        try
        {
            System.Console.Writeline(siteCollectionChild.Url);
        }
        finally
        {
            siteCollectionChild.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you dispose `SPSite siteCollectionParent` it will dispose only site collection with url `strUrl`. ie. only 1 site collection

And disposing `childCollections` or every single `siteCollectionChild` is similar. just you are disposing in a go if you dispose `childCollections`.

**NOTE:** You are disposinig every single SPSite in the web application.

Be careful about requirement and decide which one you want to dispose.